# Highlight text (string type) in Pandas DF matching text

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I have Pandas DF like:

```
name    sal
--------------
Piter   12345
Pen     10450
Paul    99995
Punk    54001
Pok     45555
```

By matching text like '45' (only in column 'sal', string type) I want text in it got red.

So in my case this text should be highlighted in red:

```
12345
10450
45555
```

So I know how to highlight max value or min value, I also can "if val in (45, '45')", but this only match by whole text in cell. I googled for "df.str.contains('45', regex=True)", but I something don't know.

My code is:

```
def color_in(val):
    if val <like '45' or something, plese help>:
        color = 'red'
    else:
        color = 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color

s = df.style.applymap(color_in, subset=['sal'])
s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in` opeartor, because working with scalars, if values are numeric change `val` to `str(val)` for cast to string:

```
def color_in(val):
    if  '45' in val:
        color = 'red'
    else:
        color = 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

Comment: OMG! It works like a charm. How could I not think of this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, without the need to define another function:

```
df.style.where(lambda val: '45' in str(val), 'color: red', subset=['sal'])
```